# Problems adding path and calling external program from Python

Tags: python, linux

I have an executable called "foo" in "/home/myname/mydir/" and am trying to call it from Python, but I am doing something basic and wrong here. Can you help me?

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append("/home/myname/mydir/")
os.system("foo") # os.system("./foo") doesn't work either
```

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`sys.path` is the path to Python libraries, not the system PATH to search for binaries. Try changing `os.environ['PATH']` instead.

```
>>> sys.path.append("/opt/local/bin")
>>> os.system("wget")
sh: wget: command not found
32512
>>> os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + '/opt/local/bin'
>>> os.system("wget")
wget: missing URL
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use the `subprocess` module instead of `os.system`, for anything serious. For `os.system`, do this:

```
os.system('/home/myname/mydir/foo ')
```

For `subprocess`:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['/home/myname/mydir/foo'])
p.communicate('')
if p.returncode != 0:
    raise Exception('foo failed')
```

If you care about foo's argv[0] being 'foo' and not '/home/myname/mydir/foo', do this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['foo'], executable='/home/myname/mydir/foo')
```

The reason `subprocess` is so much better than `os.system` is that it provides better control over the argument list: it does not require the command line to be parsed by the shell, and that avoids a whole slew of potential security problems, particularly with user-supplied filenames and such. The other reason is that `subprocess` provides better handling of errors, and better redirection of stdin, stdout, and stderr. (Not shown in the example above.)