# Python script unable to run "android" command

Tags: android, python, ubuntu

I am trying to create "avd" from python script using command :
**android create avd -n avd1 -t android-19 -s QVGA -b x86**

Everytime i run this command through Terminal i get avd created but if i am running same command from python script i a getting error which says that "android" command was not found.

Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, os

def main():
    cmd = "android create avd -n avd1 -t android-19 -s QVGA -b x86"
    print cmd
    os.system(cmd)

main()
```

What could be the possible error.

Environment : Ubuntu 13.04
Path variable set to: **export PATH=$PATH:~/android-sdks/tools/:~/android-sdks/build-tools/:~/android-sdks/platform-tools/:~/android-sdks/**

Comment: Also, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241735/problems-adding-path-and-calling-external-program-from-python

Answer (score 1):

From Python's documentation:

> Changes to `sys.stdin`, etc. are not reflected in the environment of the
>   executed command.

`os.system` has limitations. The [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module is preferable.

Try:

```
import subprocess

cmd = "android create avd -n avd1 -t android-19 -s QVGA -b x86"
subprocess.call(cmd.split())
```

Comment: i am getting an error like : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 6, in <module>
    subprocess.call(cmd.split())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 524, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: What is the value of `os.environ['PATH']`? Did you set the `$PATH` variable correctly?

Comment: Value of $PATH is there in the question itself.

Comment: I got the subprocess command running. "shell=True" was missing in the command. But still same issue that android is not found.

Comment: Do a `print os.environ['PATH']` and see what it gives you. It sounds like your Python runtime did not get the correct PATH.

Comment: Its getting the same path which i set. Could you please check if the path set by me is correct. Additionally i am using OpenJdk, could that be a problem that i need sun jdk ?

Comment: @Amber Huh. Not sure what else to say. I have a very similar setup as yours and the above works fine for me. Your error message does indicate PATH issues, though, as far as I can ascertain.