# Can't execute java code within flask application using os.system()

Tags: java, python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I have been trying to solve this issue for 5 hours 
when I try to execute the below code in the terminal it works fine. However, when I use the same code in flask application I am getting this error **(sh: 1: java: not found)**

```
import os 
environ = os.environ.copy()
os.putenv("JAVA_HOME", "/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-oracle/bin/java")
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + ":/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-oracle/bin/java/bin"
os.system("java -jar /home/../myproject/application/graphseg1.jar /home/../myproject/application/entire_text /home/.../myproject/application/segmented_text 0.40 2")
```

the above code works fine within the terminal as shown below:
[image: capture from terminal]

However, when I try to run the same code within flask application, I am getting the following error:
[image: flask_app log]

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, nginx,supervisor,gunicorn3 
supervisor configration file:

```
[program:flask_app]
directory=/home/****/myproject
environment=PATH=/tmp/enter/envs/myenvi/bin
command=/tmp/enter/envs/myenvi/bin/gunicorn application:app --timeout 9223372036
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/flask_app/flask_app.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/flask_app/flask_app.out.log
```

Comment: Can you print the value of `os.environ["PATH"]` just before the `system` call?

Comment: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-oracle/bin/java/bin` looks very fishy. `bin/java/bin`, really? Not just `/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-oracle/bin`? Keep in mind, the PATH should point to the *directory* that has `java` in it, not to the `java` executable itself; and you certainly can't add a `bin` subdirectory to an executable name and expect it to work.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you are right. I misspelt the path. Thank you so much

Comment: Since this was caused by a typo, consider deleting the question if you're allowed (questions caused by topographic errors being #2 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably using Subprocess instead. It provides pipes for STDIN, STOUT, STDERR and the option for a full shell with some inherent security warnings.

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

Seems like your path is not setup properly, like *omajd* said can you print it?

See also: [Problems adding path and calling external program from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241735/problems-adding-path-and-calling-external-program-from-python)

Comment: While it's certainly the better practice, how would switching to `subprocess` solve this problem? And the OP is already telling us enough to know how and why their PATH is wrong; the necessary information was present in revision 1 of the question.

Comment: Also, having an upvoted answer prevents a low-reputation OP from deleting their own question, despite that question being off-topic (see #2 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, and the last bullet point in the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, advising that questions that don't comply with the site's topicality rules shouldn't be answered).